# How to config line chart in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts, linechart

I am using highchart in angular js. Here is the link of highchart.
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qyntd1xa/
I am getting following error in highchart -
Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
I have added all js and html   but i am getting error

Here is my Controller

```
appControllers.controller('AdminToolController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'GlobalVariableServices', 'RolesServices', 'UserServices', 'userLoginService',
function ($scope, $modalInstance, GlobalVariableServices, RolesServices, UserServices, userLoginService) {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['MON 12', 'TUE 13', 'WED 14', 'THU 15', 'FRI 16']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [1.5, 5.5, 3.0, 2.5, 4.5]
        }]
    });
}]);
```

And here is my html code-

```
<div ng-show="tab == 2">
    <h3>TEAM MANAGEMENT</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="container">Placeholder for chart</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: Highcharts error #13 means that the code can't locate the `<div>` element it's assigned to, but your fiddle runs just fine and has no errors. Are you still having an issue?

Comment: How about using the [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)  ?